# MPI Virtual Topology Performance

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, topology

I started learning MPI and read a bit of the Standard V3.1. In the chapter for virtual topologies it says that just using a topology can improve performance. I tried to find some examples for this, but i couldn't find any. And i'm still to new to MPI to fully understand all its mechanics...

So i wanted to ask whether there is a good example to see differences by using topologies. I thought about matrix multiplication, but that would only show advantage of parallelization...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You're still new to MPI.  Disregard this issue until you have learned enough to start answering the question yourself.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If you would go on with that philosophy about any question, it is pointless to ask questions at all. If you're new to a topic and can't find an answer to a question that's bugging you all day long, would you not ask somebody about it?

Comment: Maybe, but topology is usually considered a more advanced (and fairly niche) issue of MPI. Typically you would no even need to know the topology for most MPI problems, perhaps use `MPI_Cart_Create` for most physical problems and only in some special case, assign your own topology with something like `MPI_GRAPH_CREATE`. An example of this is on the excellent deinoMPI documentationL http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/mpi_graph_create.html